# Why Is the Jefferson Method Not Susceptible to the Population Paradox?

Tags: voting-theory

When apportioning the seats of a legislative body, why does using the Jefferson method, where $P_i$ is population in state $i$, $N$ is total seats available, and we vary $Q>0$ until $$\sum_i{\bigg\lfloor\frac{P_i}{Q}\bigg\rfloor}=N$$ not leave us vulnerable to the population paradox (as using the Hamilton method would)?